# Mongoose - Populate Array With Reference Property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an array of Tags in my Post schema:

`tags: [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag' } ],`

Tag looks like this:

`{ name: String }`

When I populate the `tags` array it is of course populated with tag object literals.

Is there a way I can instead have mongoose populate the array with only the `name` string from the tag?

I have tried only specifying the name, but then `name` is returned within an object literal.

Currently the population outputs:

`[ { name: 'React' }, { name: 'JavaScript' } ]`

But I would like it to be:

`[ 'React', 'JavaScript']`

Is there a way to do this with Mongoose ?

Comment: It seems almost like your schema should instead be `[{type: String}]`, so that you're not fighting against the library the whole way.  Is there any reason you need ObjectIds in the schema but strings actually being saved?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of 'post' [Query Middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) function. This function will be triggered before the actual data is returned by Model.find() or Model.findOne() query. Inside the function you can use Array.map to transform the data to required format.

```
schema.post('findOne', function(doc) {
    // Transform the doc here.
    // Example: 
    // doc.tags = doc.tags.map(tag => tag.name);
});
```

You could also do the same for handling Model.find().

```
schema.post('find', function(docs) {
    // Transform the doc here.
    // Example: 
    // docs = docs.map(doc => {
    //     doc.tags = doc.tags.map(tag => tag.name);
    //     return doc;
    // });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a virtual that returns a reduction of the tags array:

```
schema.virtual('plainTags').get(function () {
  // first, validate if the 'tags' path is populated
  if (!this.populated('tags')) {
    return this.tags
  }
  return this.tags.reduce(function(col, Tag) {
    col.push(Tag.name) return col
  }, [])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What you were looking for is the populate "[transform](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#transform-populated-documents)" option.

Where you can trigger a function for each document that is being populated, for your use case it would look like this:

```js
item = await Parent.findById("_id").populate([{
  path: 'tags',
  transform: (document, id) => document == null ? null : document.name
}]);
```